# invalid date format in specification when trying to build gem

Tags: ruby, build, rubygems

I am writing a gem and I want to build it:

```
$ gem build llrb.gemspec
```

The gemspec contains:

```
s.date = %q{2011-12-5}
```

But I get this error:

> Invalid gemspec in [`llrb.gemspec`]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-12-5"

What is the correct date format for a gemspec? Is there something wrong with my RubyGems installation?

---

I am running RubyGems 1.8.12. With ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin11.0].

Answer (score 0):

I think it is only a missing 0. (At least with ruby 1.9.2 it would be the solution).

```
require 'rubygems'

spec = Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name = 'example'
  s.version = '1.0'
  s.summary = 'Example gem specification'
  s.date = %q{2011-12-05}
end

p spec.date #2011-12-05 00:00:00 UTC
```

Or just try

```
  s.date = Date.new(2011,12,5)
```